# How to resolve QMimeDatabase error while trying to open anaconda-navigator?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-11

I have tried to open Anaconda navigator in Windows but it fails to open with the below error:

```
QMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data

An error has been encountered at line 1 of <internal MIME data>: Premature end of document.:
```

I have tried updating and resetting and also uninstalled and re-installed ,but every time it fails with same error.

Commands tried:

1. `conda update conda`
2. `conda update anaconda-navigator`
3. `anaconda-navigator --reset`

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 0):

I soleved the same issue, trying the below.

It is worthy to try.

1 Open this file below.

C:\Users\user\.condarc

2 If whole sript are commented out by '#', delete '#'.

3 If the last line is not "env_prompt: ({base})", change it to the left one.

- I had chenged 'base' to another text, then lots of trouble occurred, then had  commented out whole. do I changed it, that is probably 'default'.